# How to locally distinguish the interior of a fractal curve from the exterior?

Tags: fractals

After staring at a small portion of a Koch snowflake, it seems to me that it is not possible to tell the inside of the snowflake from the outside if you can only see a small portion of the boundary.

Small view of the Koch snowflake:

[image: Small portion of Koch snowflake.]

Expanded view:

[image: Kock snowflake.]

**Problem:** Given a closed fractal curve and a neighborhood of a point on this curve, we would like to identify which side of the curve is the interior.

**Question:** Are there useful conditions on the fractal curve which tell us when this problem is solvable?

---

Edit: I realized there is one way to tell the interior of the Koch snowflake from the outside, with additional assumptions: if the interior is formed from triangles of side lengths $1, 1/3, 1/9, \dots$, then the exterior has triangular features of size $1/\sqrt{3}, 1/3\sqrt{3}, 1/9\sqrt{3}, \dots$.  So if you have a ruler (i.e. metric) and you know the overall size of the snowflake, you can determine locally which side is the interior.

Comment: (the boundary of) the Mandelbrot set is smooth on the inside and crunchy on the outside

Comment: How would you propose to solve this problem for a Jordan curve?  It seems to me that if you can only see a small portion of the boundary, there is no way of knowing if you are on the "inside" or "outside".

Comment: Regarding your edit:  the plane can be tiled by copies the von Koch snowflake (of two different sizes).  Using your suggested method, how do you know if you are inside a large snowflake, or outside a small snowflake?  You can't just look at a small portion of the boundary and know where you are.  You need more global information.